# Ratio of modified Bessel functions of the first kind of n'th and 0th order

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

I was messing around and found an approximation for the ratio of two [modified Bessel functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html):

$${I_N(x_0)\over I_0(x_0)}=e^{-N^2\over2x_0}, x_0>0$$
which seems to get better with larger $x_0$.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUaZa.jpg)  is the graph showing two sides of equation with $x_0$=60.

I cant find it anywhere in the literature. Could anyone please help to prove it or give some reference ?

Comment: would you mind tro write down what exactly $I_N$ is?

Comment: sure, edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some heuristics:

Take the asymptotic expansions for the modified Bessel function (large $x$):

$$
\frac{I_N(x)}{I_0(x)}\sim \frac{1-\frac{4N^2-1}{8x}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{N^4}{x^2})}{1-\frac{1}{8x}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{x^2})}$$

Now if $x>>N^2>>1 \quad (1)$
$$
\frac{I_N(x)}{I_0(x)}\sim 1-\frac{4N^2}{8x}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{N^4}{x^2})= 1-\frac{N^2}{2x}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{N^4}{x^2})
$$

Now compare with the first order expansion of $\exp$: $\exp(-N^2/2x)\sim1-\frac{N^2}{2x}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{N^4}{x^2})$

Therefore
$$
\frac{I_N(x)}{I_0(x)}\approx \exp(-N^2/2x)
$$

under assumoption (1) and the error is $\mathcal{O}(\frac{N^4}{x^2})$

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: You are welcome... please note that the assumption (1) is really crucial, you don't mention it in your question...

Comment: Well, it works reasonable (for my purposes) even for $x_0<N^2$. Here is the graph http://i.stack.imgur.com/Am4E2.jpg for $x_0=5$

Comment: the point is, that my proof is not valid in this region. for small $x_0$ one could show that a good approximation for the ratio should be $\sim x^N/N!$ where the $N!$ can be simplified if $N>>1$ by stirlings approximation.